# why my code is not covering the whole screen in mobile view its is only covering half of the screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, responsive

please help me out with this code. It looks great in the pc but covering only half of the screen in the mobile view. Do guide me out with this issue. Below is my code of HTML and CSS. I will be very grateful for your help. I think there is some problem with the container-fluid class which is, as it is not covering the whole screen

```css
body{
  /* background: no-repeat fixed url(../images/background.png); */
  font-family: 'open Sans';
  color: white;
}

/* Navbar section */

.container-fluid{
  background: no-repeat fixed url(../images/background3.png);
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 8% 15%;
  height: 710px;
}
.navbar-light{
  background-color: #78c9cb;
  color: grey;
  font-size: 200%;
}
/* Create Account Section */
.card{
   max-width: 800px;
   padding: 0;
   text-align: center;
  /* margin-top: 10%; */
}
.create{
  font-size: 3rem;
  padding:0;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
.form-group{
   padding: 0.8rem;
}

@media (max-width:800px) {
  .container-fluid{
      padding: 20% 15%;
  }
  body{
      max-height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- CSS stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384- 
JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">


<!-- Google Fonts -->
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,600,700">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alex+Brush&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css">

<title></title>
</head>

<body>

<!-- Navigation bar -->
<header id="Head">
<div class="container-fluid">
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/icon.png" width="30%" height="30%" alt="Icon"> 
</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu" 
aria-controls="menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#news">News</a>
    </li>
    <!-- <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#profile">Profile</a>
    </li> -->
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
</nav>


<!-- Registration -->
<div class="row ">
<div class="card bg-dark mx-auto">
  <div class="card-header">
    <h2 class="create">Create Account</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <form class="" action="login.php" method="post">
      <div class="form-group input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i> </span>
        </div>
        <input name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="User name" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text"> <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> </span>
        </div>
        <input name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" type="email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text"> <i class="fa fa-lock"></i> </span>
        </div>
        <input name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" type="password">
      </div>

      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="submit" value="Create 
       Account">
      <p>Have an account?<a href="login.php">Log In</a> </p>
    </form>
  </div>

  </div>

  </div>



  </div>


  </header>



 </section>




<!-- JavascriptTags  -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384- 
DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Add `padding-0;` to `container-fluid` in mobile view media query

Comment: try this `@media (max-width:375px) { .container-fluid{ padding: 0; }  }` // iphone @375

Comment: I have tried it but then also it is just covering the half width

Answer (score 0):

Add this style **@375px media queries** for **iPhone**

```
@media only screen and (max-width:375px) { 
   #Head .container-fluid{ 
       padding: 0;    
   }
}
```

**Working demo**

```css
body{
  /* background: no-repeat fixed url(../images/background.png); */
  font-family: 'open Sans';
  color: white;
}

/* Navbar section */

.container-fluid{
  background: no-repeat fixed url(../images/background3.png);
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 8% 15%;
  height: 710px;
}
.navbar-light{
  background-color: #78c9cb;
  color: grey;
  font-size: 200%;
}
/* Create Account Section */
.card{
   max-width: 800px;
   padding: 0;
   text-align: center;
  /* margin-top: 10%; */
}
.create{
  font-size: 3rem;
  padding:0;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
.form-group{
   padding: 0.8rem;
}

@media (max-width:800px) {
  .container-fluid{
      padding: 20% 15%;
  }
  body{
      max-height: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:375px) { 
   #Head .container-fluid{ 
       padding: 0;    
   }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- CSS stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384- 
JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">


<!-- Google Fonts -->
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,600,700">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alex+Brush&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css">

<title></title>
</head>

<body>

<!-- Navigation bar -->
<header id="Head">
<div class="container-fluid">
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/icon.png" width="30%" height="30%" alt="Icon"> 
</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu" 
aria-controls="menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#news">News</a>
    </li>
    <!-- <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#profile">Profile</a>
    </li> -->
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
</nav>


<!-- Registration -->
<div class="row ">
<div class="card bg-dark mx-auto">
  <div class="card-header">
    <h2 class="create">Create Account</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <form class="" action="login.php" method="post">
      <div class="form-group input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i> </span>
        </div>
        <input name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="User name" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text"> <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> </span>
        </div>
        <input name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" type="email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text"> <i class="fa fa-lock"></i> </span>
        </div>
        <input name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" type="password">
      </div>

      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="submit" value="Create 
       Account">
      <p>Have an account?<a href="login.php">Log In</a> </p>
    </form>
  </div>

  </div>

  </div>



  </div>


  </header>



 </section>




<!-- JavascriptTags  -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384- 
DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: try this :) i addedanswer :)